# German umlaut not storing correctly in postgres on linux system

Tags: linux, postgresql, xslt, encoding, character-encoding

I am working on an applicaiton which allows user to upload an xsl file which finally stored in postgres database. The xsl file contains german umlauts. I am using encoding ISO-8859-1 for one xsl and UTF-8 for another xsl.
The problem which i am facing is when i upload both these files on my windows machine, the german umlauts saved correctly in postgres but when i upload these files on linux system postgres does not saved german umlauts correctly. Instead it save them something like this "�"
Can anyone suggest what encoding should i use in xsl files so that it get correctly stored in linux system postgres.

Comment: What is the value of `client_encoding` in the session that inserts into the database? What is the `server_encoding` for the database? As what bytes are the umlauts stored when you look at the entry with `SELECT stringcol::bytea FROM tab WHERE id = 1234;`, casting the string to `bytea`?

Comment: Why are you using latin-1 for one of the files?

Comment: As an escape not a real solution, you use character-entities instead: i.e.: "ü" becomes "&#252;"